# Why aren't my css commands being processed in my html file after I render the html file using Google App Engine?

Tags: python, html, css, google-app-engine

So I have a basic form in my application that I am hosting using Google App Engine. When I type in a particular query, say 'CN', I want the CN.html file to be rendered. I have redirected my path and stuff, and used if-else to allow CN.html file to be rendered when 'CN' is queried. However, all the inline CSS commands inside the CN.html are not considered, and all I get redirected to when I query 'CN' is to the basic HTML document void of all the CSS commands. Also, the images are not displayed.

Now, I have put the CN.html file in a folder called 'templates' in my directory and all the images in a folder called 'images'.

NOTE- 'templates' and 'images' also contain the html file of my front page and their images respectively. I don't think it should be a problem, though, right?

Here, check the live example of my problem yourself:

go to www.deploymentapp.appspot.com and search for 'Computer Networks'.

So what seems to be the problem?

---

EDIT(Including all the source code files for better understanding)

CN.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Computer Network</title>
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "/stylesheets/cn.css" type = "text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id='cn'>
        <img src = "/images/CN.jpg" width = '300px' height = '400px'>
    </div>
    <div id = 'cn_heading'>
        <h1>&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbspComputer Networks</h1>
        <p class = 'pname'>by Andrew Tanenbaum</p>
    </div>
    <div id = 'buy'>
        <a href = '#'><img src = '/images/buy-now.jpg' width = '300px'     height = '100px'></a>
    <div id = 'details'>
        <p>Authored by : Andrew S. Tanenbaum, David J. Wetherall</p> 
        <p>Publisher : Pearson </p>
        <p>Price : Rs. 550 (Inclusive of taxes)</p>
    </div>

    <div id = 'description'>
            <p><h3>&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp  COMPUTER NETWORKS 5TH EDITION</h3>
Computer Networks, Fifth Edition, is the ideal introduction to the networking field. This bestseller reflects the latest networking technologies with a special emphasis on wireless networking, including 802.11, 802.16, Bluetooth&trade, and 3G cellular, paired with fixed-network coverage of ADSL, Internet over cable, gigabit Ethernet, MLPS, and peer-to-peer networks. Notably, this latest edition incorporates new coverage on 3G mobile phone networks, Fiber to the Home, RIFD, delay-tolerant networks, and 802.11 security, in addition to expanded material on Internet routing, multicasting, congestion control, quality of service, real-time transport, and content distribution.

Tanenbaum takes a structured approach to explaining how networks work from the inside out. He starts with an explanation of the physical layer of networking, computer hardware and transmission systems then works his way up to network applications.

Salient Features
<ul>
<li>Wireless networks (802.12 and 802.16)</li>
<li>The 3G networks used by smart phones</li>
<li>RFID and sensor networks</li>
<li>Content Distribution using CDNs</li>
<li>Peer-to-peer networks</li>
<li>Real-time media (from stored, streaming, and live sources)</li>
<li>Internet telephony (voice over IP)</li>
<li>Delay-tolerant networks</li>
    </ul>
</p>
       </div>


        </body>
</html>
```

CN.css

```
#cn
{
    margin-top : 50px;
    margin-left : 50px;
    box-shadow : 5px 5px 5px black;
    width : 300px;

}
#cn_heading
{
    margin-top : -448px;
    margin-left : 425px;

}

.pname
{       font-style : italic;
}

#buy
{
    margin-top : 370px;
    margin-left : 50px;

}
#details
{
    margin-left : 425px;
    margin-top : -450px;
}

#description
{
    margin-left : 425px;
    margin-top : 20px;
}
```

.yaml file

```
application: deploymentapp
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /images
  static_dir: images

- url: /stylesheets/
  static_dir: stylesheets

- url: .*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

here's the handler which handles what happens when 'Computer Networks' is queried:

```
class CNHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def write(self, *a, **kw):
        self.response.out.write(*a, **kw)
    def render_str(self, template, **params):
        t = jinja_env.get_template(template)
        return t.render(params)
    def render(self, template, **kw):
        self.write(self.render_str(template, **kw))
    def get(self):
        self.render("CN.html")
```

Comment: I can't search for _Computer Networks_, nor for _CN_. In fact, I can't seem to search for anything. Nothing is a valid subject name!

Comment: Make sure the 'C' and 'N' in Computer Networks is capitalized. I will work on the other options afterwards.

Comment: We can only speculate at what the problem is, because you haven't shown us any code. Your problem can be in several places, but without knowledge of the structure of your application (i.e., url structure, how HTML is specifying paths to CSS) you're asking for people to guess.

Comment: I have now included the source codes above. The problem seems to be that my CN.html file is not being updated even after I deploy the files. Hence the images and the styles couldnt be uploaded. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

You're css file is either not deployed or you're applications [static resources](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/staticfiles) are configured incorrectly.

For example, after searching for 'Computer Networks', the related stylesheet results in a 404.
http://www.deploymentapp.appspot.com/cn.css

In regards to the image issue, you have not specified the correct path to the image. For example:

```
<img src = "CN.jpg" width = '300px' height = '400px'>
```

Should be:

```
<img src = "/images/CN.jpg" width = '300px' height = '400px'>
```

Comment: Now this is interesting. I have already changed my image path in my html file as mentioned in my edited post above. However, even after deploying the edited file, I still see the unedited version being deployed as seen by the page source. Why is that happening?

Comment: @ManasChaturvedi Have you verified this behaviour on the local devappserver? Have you verified that your deployment was successful and the current version has been set as the default versions as this is a deployment issue and nothing else.

Comment: No..the files aren't being updated even on my local server. This is a deployment issue for sure...but how can this be tackled?